# if elif statement not working properly in python with sklearn's RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

So I'm trying to build a ml program that sorts the users input into different categories and then determines what the user wants. The problem is that in the end, I added an if elif statement that then performs different funcs based on what the RFC predicted. However the if statement is always being executed no matter what the user inputs

```
try: 
        predicted_user_input = rfc.predict(np.reshape(to_put_in_rfc, (1, -1)))
        print(predicted_user_input)

        print("RFC succesfully predicted\n")

        refined_predicted_input = predicted_user_input[0]
        print(refined_predicted_input)
except:
        print("RFC failed to predict\n")


if refined_predicted_input == 'youtube search' or 'search youtube':
            try:
                what_to_watch = input("Please enter what you would like to watch: ")
                youtubeSearch(what_to_watch=what_to_watch)
                print('Youtube search successfully executed')
            except:
                print("Youtube search failed")

elif refined_predicted_input == 'google search' or 'search google':
            try:
                what_to_search_for = input("Please enter what would you like to search for: ")
                googleSearch(what_to_search_for)
                print("Google search successfull")
            except:
                print("Google search failed")

elif refined_predicted_input == 'news search':
            news_to_search = input("Enter the topic of news you want to hear about: ")
            voice.say(newsSearch(news_to_search))
```

In this code that you see the youtube func is always executed even if the RFC predicts its 'Google search'

I tried to first make it compare with words, then actual values from a list of labels, and even tried a for loop to split down the users input into different words but nothing worked. The first if statement is always being executed

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the way python evaluates if expressions:
In this line

```
if refined_predicted_input == 'youtube search' or 'search youtube':
```

python first evaluates `refined_predicted_input == 'youtube search'` which can evaluate True or False. Next it evaluates ONLY `'search youtube'` which will **always** return True. So your if statements will always evaluate to True. To fix this you will need to update your if statements to something like this:

```
if refined_predicted_input in {'youtube search', 'search youtube'}:
    ...
```

You have this issue multiple times, so you should fix all of them

Answer (score 0):

consider below two scenarios where in
first scenario " qt==yt_search or search_yt " will always be True as the search_yt always evaluates to be True as we have non string in it .
In the second scenario "qt==yt_search or qt==search_yt " checks for both the conditions as in conditional True statement and results in answer based on the condition

```
yt_search='first'
search_yt='second'
qt='last'
if qt==yt_search or search_yt:
  print('hey')
else:
  print('not a match')
```

output:

```
hey
```

```
yt_search='first'
search_yt='second'
qt='last'
if qt==yt_search or qt==search_yt:
#(F or F which results in F)
  print('hey')
else:
  print('not a match')
```

output:

```
not a match
```